# How do I move my character without his armor squishing?

Tags: modifiers, transforms

After I try to move my character with the "g" key, his armor starts squishing and it doesn't stay on his body.[image][image] This is what my character looks like before I start moving him with the "g" key.

Comment: the weight is probably bad, you need to correct, you can do it in Weight Paint mode, or assign and remove the vertices from the groups with the help of the Vertex Groups list

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've figured out the problem. My character's armor was shrink-wrapping to a high poly model that was hidden. :)